# Previous and Next - DataTables

Tags: datatable

I am using DataTables, I would like to send the pagination, but remove the previous and the next, is this possible? If yes like.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider reviewing this link and editing your post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Removing the next and previous buttons is done by adding this option to your datatable:

```
"bPaginate": false
```